# Submit button is rendering after pressing clear button

Tags: r

In my application below, everything is working well, as once I select filter and submit, the data is loading good.
I click on the clear button, and all data is removed.

Problem is if I press the submit button again, the data is not loading. Can anyone please help?

````r
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
````

### Column {data-width=650}

#### Chart A

```
selectInput("Tic","",choices = c("",as.character(iris$Species)),selected = "")
actionButton("Submit","Submit")
actionButton("Clear","Clear")
tableOutput("table")


     data2 <- eventReactive(input$Submit,{
      if(input$Tic != ""){
      iris <- iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$Tic)
      }
        })


output$table <- renderTable({
  data2()
})

      observeEvent(input$Clear,{
      output$table <- renderTable({

})
      })
```

Comment: ok i tried that also :). But it is not solving my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is when you click the "clear" button you are setting

```
output$table <- renderTable({})
```

and this replaces the existing

```
output$table <- renderTable({data2()})
```

this means that `output$table` is no longer dependent on `data2()` so nothing will happen when `data2` changes any more. You've permanently changed the output to always show an empty table.

Rather than changing the output, it would be better if you made `data2` a `reactiveVal()`. That way you can manually reset it's value. For example

```
data2 <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(input$Submit, {
  if (input$Tic != "") {
    data2(iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$Tic))
  }
})

observeEvent(input$Clear, {
  data2(NULL)
})

output$table <- renderTable({
  data2()
})
```

So rather than an `eventReactive`, `data2` is a `reactiveVal` so we can change it's value when we `observeEvent` for either the submit or clear. When you have `data2 <- eventReactive(input$Submit,{})`, there is no other way for you to change the value of `data2` when any other event happens.

You can get more examples here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html (specifically patterns 3 and 4)